# transform texture position on DirectX Meshes

Tags: directx, transform, textures

is there a way that I can adjust the uv positions of textures on my mesh when rendering without manually recalculating and changing all the UVs? If so, which would be more efficient? I read something about a transformation that might work but it sounded like it might not work if I'm also transforming the position and size of my mesh. This would be a problem so please take this into account when considering any possibilities.
(Sorry if I'm talking weird. I'm a bit sleep deprived, atm.)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit sleep deprived

I suggest to get some sleep instead of programming with directx.

> is there a way that I can adjust the uv positions of textures

[`IDirect3DDevice9::SetTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0, &matrix)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). IN shaders transformations must be done manually.